# Short story about park ranger with drones

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short sci-fi story in the late 90's or early 2000's about a park ranger patrolling wilderness that had been closed to any human activity. There also were drones to keep an eye on things. I think it was in a book with a collection of stories.

Comment: @user14111 They didn't have drones back then as we understand them now. UAVs were still fringe military tech; although their history goes back some way, they weren't on the public's radar until fairly recently. One of the "scifi" things about games like Shadowrun, which were popular in the 90s, was that you could play a character who used drones a lot.

Comment: Regular people at that time would have not believed that at one point the wilderness would be closed to everybody and that drones could be used to patrol the area and keep people out. we have reached that level in no time at all.

Comment: There's something like that in Childhood's End where a park ranger patrols a reserve  in Africa by some kind of holographic projection technology.